# How to conditionally fire segue based on block-based network operation in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a block-based network function that I want to only allow a segue to commence when it is successful.  This is an attempt at authentication:

```
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"in process");     
    if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"succcess");

        }else{
            NSLog(@"failure");
         }
    }];
```

How can I commence a segue conditionally with this statement in a viewController?

Answer (score 3):

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier@"YourSegueIdentifierThatYouSetInStoryboard"];` should do the trick if I understand the question correctly.

Edit 1:

To fire this code on main thread, wrap your code like that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier@"YourSegueIdentifierThatYouSetInStoryboard"]; 
});
```

Comment: @Atma Yep, that's true. So dispatch the `performSegueWithIdentifier` to the main queue if you're unsure as to whether the completion block is run on the main queue.